# Excel average values in time step

Tags: excel, time, filter, average

I have a problem with analyzing data measurement in Excel. Here is my issue.

In column A input is time (day.month  hour), in column B it is day in year. From column C to I are numbers from measurement analyzer. 
As you can see from the Excel Prnt Scrn, in single day we measured values in different time. I have to calculate average of all values (from value 1 to value 7) for specific day.

Example: average of values in Time 1.1.2012 (average values 1.1.2012 at 0:59, 1:59, 2:59 ….).

The problem is that I have more than 9000 rows with different time steps. I tried with Filter function, but I only manage to get time from older to newest!

Appreciate for any useful advice.

[image: Image url:]

Comment: [AVERAGEIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx) or [AVERAGEIFs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/averageifs-function-HA010047493.aspx)?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you be more specific?

Comment: If I try to use AVERAGE IF function, I have a problem with condition which is date (but have different time!). Any ideas how to write condition, to define only date (like 1.1.2012) without time?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want average of `ValueN` for each `Day` regardless of specific `Time` (as long as it is corresponds to that day in the year) where N is 1-7?

Answer (score 0):

First, assign a value for all cells in the Day column using the Date number type. You will need to use Find and Replace to change all the "." to "/" in your Time column for this to work (i.e. DD.MM.YY HH:MM becomes DD/MM/YY HH:MM). Copy the Time column into the Day column. Highlight the Day column, right click, and select Format Cells. Change the format to Date, and it will cut off the time values. If you want a number for Julian Day and not the date, insert a new column and see this article for calculating day of the year: http://inanecoding.co.uk/2012/10/converting-excel-date-to-julian-day-of-year-number/

Second, use the Subtotal function under the Data tab to average each day's values. The this will work with date or Julian Day (or any column containing more than one unique value). This will change the appearance of the sheet but all the base data will still be there. However, for convenience of switching between raw and averaged data, I'd make a copy of the sheet before proceeding. Click Subtotal and in the dropdown menu "For each change in:" select which column (Date or Day) you want to use as a grouping. For the "Use function" menu, select Average. Below, check the columns you want to find averages for (Value 1-7). Click okay.

Since you have 9000 records, this may take a few seconds. Play around with the 1,2,3 boxes in the upper left corner to see the level of detail you want in the resulting spreadsheet.